# how to add collation( utf8_general_ci) using install schema in magento2?

Tags: magento2, install-script

I want to create table using install schema in magento2 with column collation( utf8_general_ci) .

how to do this?

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this below script in InstallSchema.php file :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        // Get vendor_sampletable table
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('vendor_sampletable');
        // Check if the table already exists
        if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create vendor_sampletable table
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'title',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Title'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'description',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Description'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'summary',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Summary'
                )                
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Created At'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                    'Status'
                )
                ->setComment('Table Comment')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8')
                ->setOption('collate', 'utf8_general_ci');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. So we can change charset and collate from setOption.

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera. I take reference from /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php file